# Ruby rufus scheduler

Tags: ruby, rufus-scheduler

I have this very simple code to run rufus/scheduler:

```
require 'rufus/scheduler'
require 'rubygems'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.every '1s' do 
puts "Hello world"

end
scheduler.join
```

This doesn't seem to work and I get no result.

Comment: How do you run it? ruby or irb? what version of ruby? No output at all? Your code works for me, although @hwatkins code is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including the wrong gem, try this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rufus-scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.every '1s' do 
puts "Hello world"

end
scheduler.join
```

Comment: `require 'rufus-scheduler'` doesn't work for me, `rufus/scheduler` worked fine. 
Let's say i am running scheduler.every '5m' 
what happens if my code doesn't complete execution in that time? Does a new instance of execution abort my current process and starts over again?

Comment: Try doing 'gem install rufus-scheduler' first.  Make sure 'rubygems' is required first.  It looks like there is no check to see if code is still running from a previous invocation, so you would have to synchronize that outside of rufus.